# (new Array(x)).map stranges

Tags: javascript, arrays

I found strange behavior ( tested at Chrome )

```
[1,2].map(function() { console.log(arguments); })
// [1, 0, Array[2]]
// [2, 1, Array[2]]
// [undefined, undefined]
```

and that's ok -- ok as in documentation
But

```
(new Array(20)).map(function() { console.log(arguments); })
//[undefined × 20]
```

It doesn't use callback ( no actions, `debugger` inside doesn't work etc. ). Why??

Syntax `new Array(arrayLength)` should create array with given length. And it does. But what with `.map`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned
>   values, including undefined. It is not called for missing elements of
>   the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been
>   deleted or which have never been assigned a value).

When you declare an array using `new Array()`, all of the elements are undefined, but they have not been *assigned* `undefined` as a *value*.  Therefore, they are skipped in the call to `map()`.

You can use `join()` and `split()` to explicitly assign `undefined` to each element, and you'll then get the expected output:

```js
(new Array(20).join(undefined).split(undefined)).map(function() { console.log(arguments); })
```

Comment: Hehe.. You beat me to it :-)

Comment: More elegant in ES6: `[...Array(20)].map(function(...args) { console.log(args); })`